# Is there a software for aggregating frequent flyer accounts?

Tags: gratis, android, osx

I have multiple frequent flyer programs in multiple airlines. So, opening the respective sites and looking at them is a lot of effort.

So, is there a software where I can add my frequent flyer accounts, and see my points for each account at one place?

An OSX app or a webapp or an android app on mobile would do. Preferably a gratis software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a software. But, there is a freemium service which helps aggregate loyalty points at a single place. It is [awardwallet](https://awardwallet.com/). It currently supports almost all major frequent miles programs, credit cards programs and other services like hotels, restaurant points, etc.

Pretty much solves my purpose.